# Getting 401 unauthorized for every protected api request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have decoupled my Resourse server from the Authorization server and I can get access token from my authorization but when am trying to access a protected resource on my resource server i always get "Authorization has been denied for this request.". I have followed some posible solution and suggestion to make sure that my owin midleware references are same for my resource and authozation but still there is no win;

Here Is My StartUp(Resousource server)

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(NetAppWeb.Startup))]

  namespace NetAppWeb



public partial class Startup 
 {

   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config); // wire the web api to the owin server

    }
    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        //Token Consumption
        //we are configuring the Resource Server to accept (consume only) tokens with bearer scheme
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new   
        {
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
StartUp.cs (Authorization Server)

public partial class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();//configure API routes
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config); //wires up Asp.Net Web Api to owin Server
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),  
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1), //1 day 
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider() 
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

Comment: After long debbugging and troubleshooting the code i found that on my Startup.cs for Resource server i have called ConfigureAuth(app) method  instead of  ConfigureOuAuth(app) so  configureOAuth(IAppBuilder app) method the start were i set token consumtion was not hit

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a similar issue as you and whilst the cause of my problem was different, your post lead me to figure it out.

Just for awareness for others the configuration of OAuth needs to occur before the call to `app.UseWebApi` otherwise you'll always get at 401 response.

Comment: Yes Richard this took me days to figure it out also